# screen lock + Orientation change = black screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I'm using GlSurfaceView to draw my game. Initialization happens on java side, drawing on native c++.

Now I've encountered a problem:

When user starts my game, locks the screen (by pressing power button to shut down the screen), then rotates the device from landscape to portrait, unlocks the screen (by pressing power button and then unlocking the touch screen), my game repeatedly was left with blank black screen.

My game can handle rotation itself just fine (the screen is locked to landscape mode, `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`)

Lock screen/sleep mode itself proves no problem.

But the combination of the two constantly causes the black screen bug to happen. Logcat doesn't say anything of use, I think.

Comment: If you lock the screen, don't cause an orientation change, and then unlock all rendering is correct then?